# How do we go from $f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$ to $dy = f'(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, limits

As far as I know, the derivative of $y$ is defined as:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}h = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

So $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a limit, not a fraction of real numbers. I often read expressions like:

$$dy = f'(x)dx$$

How do we go from $f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$ to $dy = f'(x)dx$? Clearly not multiplying both sides for $dx$.

The [answer from the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio#answer-21209) says that:

\begin{align*}
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx} \text{(chain rule)} \\
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac1{\frac{dx}{dy}} \text{(Inverse Function theorem)}
\end{align*}

This can help me transforming $f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$ to $\frac{dy}{du} = f'(x) \frac{dx}{du}$.

Then how can I proceed getting rid of $du$?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x_1\to x} x_1 - x$?

Comment: Check your definitions of $dx$. The derivative was historically introduced by Fermat as a measure of slope of continuous functions.

Comment: You definitions are at least strange. We always have $\lim_{x\to x_1}(x-x_1)=0$. If $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{x\to x_1}(f(x)-f(x_1))=0$. Thus, your symbols $dx,df$ make little sense. See what I link above.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the link in Peter Tamaroff's comment.

Comment: Putting a $d$ in front of something does not mean "take the limit of this particular thing," nor is $\lim \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}=\frac{\lim\Delta f}{\lim\Delta x}$ (as you have essentially written) valid. Basically, you are making up rules and definitions that make everything inconsistent and meaningless.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading Arkamis' comment.

Comment: I have rewritten the question trying to be more clear on what I cannot understand.

Comment: [See my response here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435950/understanding-differentials/436254#436254)